# Espaçamento de células á direita

Tags: html, css

Preciso alinhar uma imagem a esquerda e um texto no centro, mas na mesma linha. O código que usei foi usando tabelas, que não é necessário, mas achei que ajudaria:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img  width="40" height="40" src="comeback.jpg"/></td>
    
    <td> Banana é bom</td> 
  </tr>
 
</table>
```

mas não consigo centralizar o texto, nem com o espaçamento da tabela. Como resolvo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, espero que isso possa ajuda-lo.

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <td width="50"><img width="40" height="40" src="comeback.jpg"></td>

        <td style="text-align: center;"> Banana é bom</td> 
      </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Deu certo, valeu!